# Would it be considered rude to audition for a solo that's not in my part?

Tags: trumpet, audition

In my college wind ensemble, we're playing the (band version of) Danzon no. 2 by Arturo Marquez. In the band version, there's trumpet parts and flugelhorn parts, and the band director assigned me to one of the flugelhorn parts. In the piece, there's also a really big trumpet solo, and so he decided to open auditions to se who can do it best.

Would it be considered rude for me, someone assigned to a flugelhorn part, to audition for the trumpet solo? I really love the piece, I've listened to it so many times, and I feel like I could do the solo justice, but at the same time I don't want anyone who was assigned one of the trumpet parts to feel like I `stole' their solo or anything like that.

Comment: Is it this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LonUO6eL08&t=415s

Comment: If the director doesn't mind, go for it, and please leave ego out of it.  Every audition you do is good experience.  Also note that to be an asset to the ensemble, be reliable (show up, wear the "uniform" well, do not get lost, follow the director religiously, come back from breaks a little early, etc., etc., and you'll get picked to fill in for other solos when someone comes down with a stomach bug.

Answer (score 3):

If it's open auditions, then it's open auditions. However, this is a question for the ensemble director. "Am I eligible to audition for the part?".

Comment: I agree with this answer.  I'd add that it also depends on how you relate with the group.  Are a "just one of the gang" or do you think you're the best and therefore deserve the part?  Do you get most of the solos, or is it rare? Etc.